# Keeping State After Component Unmounts

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an `Auth` component which is responsible for both *login* & *sign up*. I simply receive a prop (`isSignup`) and display the appropriate form fields. I also use `react-router`:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route
        path="/signup" exact
        render={() => <Auth isSignup />} />
    <Route
        path="/login" exact
        render={() => <Auth />} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

In the `Auth` component I have a state which holds the values of the form fields.

I'd like to keep the state of `Auth` after it unmounts, i.e when `react-router` no longer renders it, so I can keep the values when the user switches between `/signup` and `/login`.

Is there a way to do this without global state management (e.g Redux)?

Comment: While you said you'd want to avoid Redux, to be fair, this is exactly one of the problems that Redux was meant for - passing state between non-parent-child relations. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: @Nit Because this project might be really small to be using Redux. If there's no other way then I'll use it.

Comment: You can keep it small while using redux.  Use redux to only handle authorization state.  Use component state to handle everything else.

Comment: @MEnf Could you please elaborate a bit more? I'm not sure how to implement this?

Comment: Sure thing.  What I meant to say is, redux should only be used when it is necessary.  https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367.  Most people assume that all of their state needs to be maintained in Redux, however, in my opinion, you really should only store state that you want to use globally inside of it.  Form data, user input, etc.  can be handled/stored inside a react component.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper which stores the state above the components:

```
class AuthWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return ([
            <Route
                key="signup"
                path="/signup" exact
            >
                <Auth
                    state={this.state}
                    setState={(state) => this.setState(state)}
                    isSignup
                />
            </Route>,
            <Route
                key="login"
                path="/login" exact
            >
                <Auth
                    state={this.state}
                    setState={(state) => this.setState(state)}
                />
            </Route>
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then this component can be used, which stores the state over those routes.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <AuthWrapper />
</BrowserRouter>
```

You would just need to use the state and setState in the params instead in the Auth component.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Redux for this purpose, but you still want to share this specific state across your app, then there are a few ways to go about it. If you want to stay "Reacty", then you really have 2 options:

1. Pass state as props
2. Use a Provider

If you just want something that works but isn't necessarily the React way, you have more options (like setting `window.isLoggedIn` and toggling it at will... which I don't recommend).

For this answer, we'll focus on the "Reacty" options.

## Pass state as props

This is the default approach with React. Track your `isLoggedIn` variable somewhere at the root of your component tree, then pass it down to your other components via props.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { isLoggedIn: false }
  logIn = () => this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
  logOut = () => this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route
          path="/signup" 
          exact
          render={() => (
            <Auth 
              isSignup
              isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
              logIn={this.logIn}
              logOut{this.logOut} 
            />
          )} 
        />
        <Route
          path="/login" 
          exact
          render={() => (
            <Auth 
              isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
              logIn={this.logIn}
              logOut{this.logOut} 
            />
          )} 
        />
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

This works but gets tedious as you need to pass `isLoggedIn`, `logIn`, and `logOut` to almost every component.

## Use a Provider

A `Provider` is a React component that passes data to all its descendants via `context`.

```
class AuthProvider extends Component {
  state = { isLoggedIn: false }
  logIn = () => this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
  logOut = () => this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      isLoggedIn: this.state.isLoggedIn,
      logIn: this.logIn,
      logOut: this.logOut
    }
  }

  static childContextTypes = {
    isLoggedIn: PropTypes.bool,
    logIn: PropTypes.func,
    logOut: PropTypes.func
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.children}
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Then, you initialize your app by wrapping the whole thing in `AuthProvider`:

```
<AuthProvider>
  <BrowserRouter>
    // routes...
  </BrowserRouter>
</AuthProvider>
```

And in any component of your app, you will be able to access `isLoggedIn`, `logIn`, and `logOut` via `this.context`.

You can read more about the `Provider` pattern and how it works in [this excellent article from Robin Wieruch](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-provider-pattern-context/).

---

notes:

1. It's common for components to receive `context` as props using a higher order component, but I left that out of the answer for brevity. [Robin's article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-provider-pattern-context/) goes into this further.
2. You may recognize the `Provider` pattern as one that `react-redux` and other state management libraries utilize. It's fairly ubiquitous at this point.

Comment: I think context should be avoided in cases like this. The React docs point out that it probably shouldn't be used and is [likely to change](https://github.com/acdlite/rfcs/blob/1e25818e47037a7de80e95793c4129e9887d6f2b/text/0000-new-version-of-context.md)

Comment: @GregorySims agreed. This is a fairly simple case, but Redux is probably still a better option. "It is far more likely that Redux is the right solution to your problem than that context is the right solution." - the docs